# How to remove 'Undefined' status on forEach function variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Im a beginner to coding JS. When im trying to create an array function for diplaying object reference. I write it on the VS code. See the image for the details.

[image]

The problem is that i want to remove the 'undefined' status that is printed on the cmder. Im using Node and cmder to run the code.

[image]

Hope this clear for you to understand my problem. Thanks

Comment: You're printing values inside your for each, and then printing the return of `foodList` (which is `undefined` since forEach will return undefined). Call your `foodList` method without the `console.log`

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or of [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are not very helpful. Put a [mcve] and (if applicable) text of the exception in the question itself. The editor has buttons and [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help you format it so it is readable. Provide a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) if you're asking about HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

Comment: A tip from my side, since you want to perform an action on an array, I'd suggest you to take a moment and read the following article:
https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d
Regarding your original question: `const foodList = items.forEach(.......)` will fix it

Comment: Okay thanks! Sorry, im a beginner and just tried the first time i used stackoverflow. Really helps and sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing

```
console.log(foodList(animal))
```

this `console.log` is returning undefined

do this

```
foodList(animal)
```

Answer (score 2):

- You are logging the return value of `foodList`.
- `foodList` returns the return value of `forEach`.
- `forEach` always returns `undefined`

If you don't want to log that, then remove the `console.log()` from around the return value of `foodList`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's my fault, i didnt know that console.log return undefined when using forEach(). Sorry everyone, my bad. Thanks for the helps!